# R: tiff( ) won't compress or set resolution to 300 ppi

Tags: r, plot, tiff

I am trying to save some graphs using R for publication.  I want to have them compressed with lzw and have the resolution at 300.  For some reason it won't allow me to do this.  In fact, it seems like R is ignoring some of the variables I set.

For the code example,

```
tiff(file="file.tiff", 
            width=6.83, height=6.83, units="in", 
            pointsize="12", compression = "lzw", 
            bg="white", res=300, antialias = "none" )
```

outputs an uncompressed file of size 28 x 28 inches and a resolution of 72 ppi.

A reproducable example would be

```
hist(rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
```

Here is the output of ImageMagick for file.tiff

```
Image: file.tiff
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2049x2049+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianess: MSB
  Colorspace: sRGB
  ...
  Compression: None
  ...
  Filesize: 16.8MB
```

I tested this on another Apple running 10.7 and get the same results.  As can be seen, even when using the options to compress and set the resolution at 300 dpi, the output does not follow the options.

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example? You specify that you want 6.83 inches times 300 ppi or an image size of 2049 pixels on each side. You say the output is 28 inches times 72 ppi which is an image size of 2016 pixels. So you are getting the image size you asked for, but there is confusion about the specs.

Comment: This is a problem with OS X no longer including X11 by default. I've outlined the steps to resolve this problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218305/tiff-resolution-and-compression-are-not-reliably-set-in-osx

Comment: Is it perhapds related to this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880558/tiff-plot-generation-and-compression-r-vs-gimp-vs-irfanview-vs-photoshop-fil

Answer (score 1):

I verified your example with R 2.15.1 on GNU/Linux by appending

```
hist(rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
```

to your `tiff()` call and checked the resulting file `"file.tiff"` with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php)'s command line tool `identify` (most output omitted):

```
Image: file.tiff
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2049x2049+0+0
  Resolution: 300x300
  Print size: 6.83x6.83
[...]
  Compression: LZW
[...]
  Filesize: 70KB
[...]
```

The R command seems to do exactly what you intend to do. I suspect that either you create the TIFF file not in the manner you describe or the tool you use to check the TIFF file's properties is faulty.

Comment: There is another option, that I entered the options correctly but it is not working.  I have examined the file in ImageMagick and do not get the results you get.  Instead I get a file that is not compressed and no information on the resolution.  See my edit in the original post.

Comment: You added a new important detail: you're using the Mac OS X version of R. Maybe the [R-SIG-Mac](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac) mailing list is a good place to post your question.

Comment: I just checked the example on a Mac with OS X 10.5.8 and R 2.12.2 and I also got an uncompressed file, so the problem seems to have been around for longer.

Comment: I have the same problem with R 3.0 on OS X 10.7.5.